# Errata in Algebra Demystified book?

Tags: polynomials

So can someone explain why there's an example that states:

$\displaystyle x^6 - \left(\frac{1}{64}\right) = x^6 - \left(\frac12\right)^6 = \left(x^3 - \frac12\right)\left(x^3 + \frac12\right)$

Comment: Well, if you copied this faithfully, they dropped the cubing of the $1/2$'s in the right-most expression.

Comment: Yes I did, it is page 143. And yes i think you're right 1/8 or missing the cube.

Comment: What's the best way to format your formulas. Is it MathJax? Sorry first time here and probably i shouldn't ask this here. Thanks

Comment: Yes, MathJax, which is operationally LaTeX. The FAQ has some discussion of this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that each $1/2$ ought to be $1/2^3$. The factorization is trivial. It is just the diffidence of squares: $(y - a)(y + a) = y^2 - a^2$. In this case, $y = x^3$ and $a = 1/2^3$.